# 400 Bad Request Cloudinary Upload Error in React + Nodejs + mySQl

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

I am currently building a Full stack Web App with React, MySQL, Nodejs, Express and Cloudinary, I am having issues uploading to Cloudinary, for security reasons, I didnt post my true upload_preset here
The code below is my React code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./Upload.css";
import Axios from 'axios';

function Upload() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

const upload = () => {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", image[0]);
    formData.append("upload_preset", "fzqyat");
    Axios.post(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/williampepple/image/upload`, formData).then((response) => {
       const fileName = response.data.public_id;

       Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/upload", {
           title: title,
           description: description, 
           image: fileName}); 
});
;} 

return (
    <div className="Upload">
    <h1>Create a Post</h1>
    <div className="UploadForm">   
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title..." 
        onChange={(event) =>{setTitle(event.target.value);
        }}
        /> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description..."
        onChange={(event) =>{setDescription(event.target.value);
        }}
        />
        <input type="file" onChange={(e) =>setImage(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={upload}>Upload</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
}
export default Upload
```

Below is my Index.js file in my Nodejs Folder:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

const userRoute = require('./Routes/User');
app.use("/user", userRoute);

const uploadRoute = require('./Routes/Upload');
app.use("/upload", uploadRoute);

app.listen(3001, (req, res) => {
    console.log("server running..");
});
```

Below is my Upload route file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const db = require('../config/db')

router.post('/', (req, res)=> {
    const title = req.body.title
    const description = req.body.description
    const image = req.body.image 

    db.query(
        "INSERT INTO Uploads(title, description, image) VALUES (? , ? , ?);", [title, description, image],
        (err, results)=>{
            console.log(err);
            res.send(results);
         }
        );
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you please log/print and share the full response you receive from Cloudinary for when an upload doesn't succeed?

Comment: The errors I saw on my console are as follows:

POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/williampepple/image/upload 400 (Bad Request)
 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: request failed with status code 400 
 at CreateError(createError.js)
 at settle(settle.js:17)
 at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad(xhr.js:62)

Comment: Could you log the value of `image[0]` when the request fails? Also, could you try to passing "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/sample.jpg" as the value of the "file" parameter (hardcoded) for one request to see if the upload succeeds? Oftentimes, the issue is the value for the "file" parameter that is passed. Another thing to check is your upload preset, to make sure it is marked as "Unsigned" on Cloudinary (Settings -> Upload tab).